# Share Photos from mobile without losing metadata?

Tags: metadata, photos, mobile-phone

I am frequently* sent phone-made Photos from trips from other people's Smartphones and likewise want to easily share new photos from trips together with them. The standard methods have long been WhatsApp or Viber, since they cause the Photos to be downloaded (on Android) or easily manually downloaded (on iOS).

However, both apps unconditionally strip *all* privacy-relevant metadata. When privately sharing photos, however, it would be vastly preferable to preserve at least the date metadata, since it is fundamental for correctly sorting the Photos; By default apps fall back to the creation date stored in the file-system, but unlike exif meta-data, this information can easily get lost when transferring the files to other devices. (Also, it usually is at least by a few days off compared to the original metadata).

Is it somehow possible to preserve the metadata, without losing convenience compared to sending by WhatsApp/Viber? The convenience aspect is important, because I am the one who cares about receiving the metadata, so I need to convince other people to use the solution.

---

<sup>* Until March 2020 anyway...</sup>

Comment: there was such thing called email before WhatsApp was introduced. i don't use any messengers at all. mail.ru will let you by-pass the (sending) mail size limitation, however the best way is still sharing links to clouds. for example dropbox let generate you links that are valid only for 7 days. that even work with sms ;)

Comment: @alecxs Still has the issue, that I can't realistically make people send me photos that way. I send photos by using Google Photos (since they are there already anyway), but if I can't offer an *easy* solution, I will keep *receiving* photos with stripped metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, send photos as *files*, but not as photos. When you send them like photo WhatsApp compresses them and they lose metadata and quality. Try send images as Documents/Files.

The steps you should follow while sending from **Android**:

1. Open a WhatsApp conversation
2. Click on attach icon > Document.
3. Click on Browse other documents.
4. Now select the image you want to send.
5. To add more images, tap and hold on a photo to select, keep on selecting the photos you want to send.

The steps you should follow while sending from **iPhone**:

1. *Open Photos* app.
2. *Select photo(s)* you want to share.
3. Click *Share* Button *(in bottom-right corner)*.
4. Scroll down and *Save to Files*.
5. *Save them* where you want.
6. *Open WhatsApp*.
7. Click on *Attach Icon* then *Document*.
8. Select the files *(the photos you saved recently)* you want to share.
9. To add more images, tap *Select* button top-right corner.

---

***Congrats!** Now you can send them without losing quality or metadata!*

<sup>*There’s no limit on how many photos you can send this way.*</sup>

Comment: Sadly, this implies some pretty heavy compromise in terms of usability :/ I can do it that way at the cost of annoyance when selecting the photos. On iOS especially, where I need to remove the "files" copy afterwards. -- But to ask other people to go through those steps to send me photos is asking too much. Most importantly, they definitely won't remember the next time they send me photos, so I'd have to request resending the photos every time.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions, as it only encourages other users to ask more of the same.